# Acceder a funciones javascript en una página abierta en una pestaña de otra página en otra pestaña siendo ambas páginas del mismo dominio

Tags: javascript, jquery

Partiendo de dos páginas en el mismo dominio A y B abiertas en diferentes pestañas o ventanas del navegador.

¿Puedo acceder a funciones en una página desde la otra?
Es decir, pasar parámetros y ejecutar funciones en una página B de la pagina A? ¿Como se puede hacer esto ?.

No necesito la ejecución de esas funciones para devolver los resultados a la otra página, sólo la ejecución de la función en la pagina donde se halle.

Mi primera idea es utilizar el objeto localstorage de HTML5 sabiendo que los eventos se pueden ejecutar en una página abierta cuando se cambia el valor de cualquier variable de la localstorage por otra página bajo el mismo dominio.
La página que oye estos cambios en localstorage puede ejecutar eventos y utilizar los nuevos valores asignados a la variable localstorage como parametro de entrada a la función y ya esto sería equivalente a ejecutar funciones pasando parametros.

Queremos compatibilidad minima con IE11 y localstorage la soporta

Otra forma que igual no es tan compatible es usar la api de websockets de html5 y no se si esta puede presentar ventajas frente a localstoraje.

¿Hay alguna otra manera de hacer esto que no este contemplando?

Gracias de antenano por vuestra ayuda

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc.

Comment: Espero que reabran pronto la pregunta. Mientras tanto, por favor, lee acerca de [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Usando_web_workers). Cuando se reabra te pongo un ejemplo de uso.

Comment: @OscarGarcia muchas gracias por tu ayuda y espero tu solucion con impaciencia. Tenia ya hoy que empezar a ir aplicando a un desarrollo en mi empresa que necesita esto y pensaba ir cotejando con las ayudas por aqui pero parece que ahora este recurso de ayuda se me va a atrasar bastante.

Comment: Mi voto de apertura ha sido emitido, pero deben votar cuatro personas más. Fue un fallo escribir en inglés la pregunta en la comunidad de SO en castellano :) por cierto, bienvenido a la comunidad.

Comment: Me equivoqué de workers, quería referirme a [shared workers (trabajadores compartidos)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker), pero estoy viendo que no están soportados a día de hoy por Windows Edge ni IE. Mediante [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) puedes montar una aproximación mediante temporizadores (chapucilla). Lo mejor por ahora es una comunicación con un servidor externo, por ejemplo mediante websockets, que sea el que orqueste la comunicación entre ventanas del navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes también usar `window.postMessage()` para emitir mensajes y `window.addEventListener('message', function (message) {})` para leerlos.
La documentación de [MDN no está traducida al español](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), pero su uso es relativamente sencillo (y si originalmente escribiste tu pregunta en inglés no creo que sea un problema). Eso sí, esto funciona si la página emisora tiene una referencia a la receptora (la receptora es un iframe o ha sido abierta por la emisora).